# Click event on Angular Material Design Gridlist

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm going through [Angular Material Design Gridlist](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.gridList) and they have not mentioned anything about handling hover/click on the grids.
So, is there a way to do it or should I use buttons inside each grid to handle click events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just giving 1 more option for this to work:
[Angular Bottom Sheet](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.bottomSheet). Here click on the '**Show as Grid**' to see clickable grid items.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming across this using material-ui, you can use the `onClick` attribute to the same effect.

Comment: can you post any example?

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a `ng-click="foo(bar)"` to the `<md-grid-tile>` element:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJggEb

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the `ng-click` event to the grid-list. See:

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNeeaa)
(click yellow)